# Is there a clean way to call an external sdk with Java files in React Native?

Tags: java, android, typescript, react-native, command-line-interface

I have a React Native cli project for an Android app. I want to use a java sdk to call some functions from there for my Android app. Since this is an sdk that changes I don't want to change the java code inside of this (so I can't change the code to use NativeModules). Is there a clean solution for my problem or would it be possible to make another Folder where I have Java files that implement the NativeModules and just call the original Java files from the sdk?

Answer (score 1):

You should create Native module as described in RN documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android because you need to provide a way of communication between JS and Native side.